# SugarCRM - Add leads with auto-incremented ID

Tags: api, soap, sugarcrm

I use the SOAP API to add new leads to SugarCRM. Additionally, I use a plugin to assign an auto-incremented lead ID whenever a new lead is created (http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/autoincrement/).

Now, the plugin works fine, if I create a new lead via frontend. But, if I use the SOAP API, the function from the module, which assigns the auto-increment ID to the lead, does not trigger.

I create the lead via

```
    $module = 'Leads'; 

    $params = array(
        'session'           =>  $session,
        'module_name'       =>  $module,
        'name_value_list'   =>  array(
            array('name' => 'id',               'value' => ''),
            //array('name' => 'int_lead_id_c',  'value' => ''),             
            array('name' => 'first_name',       'value' => $_POST["first_name"]),
            array('name' => 'last_name',        'value' => $_POST["last_name"]),
            array('name' => 'phone_home',       'value' => $_POST["phone"]),
            array('name' => 'email1',           'value' => $_POST["email"]),
            array('name' => 'assigned_user_id', 'value' => '1'),
            )
        );  

    //Create the Lead record
    $lead_result = $soapclient->call('set_entry', $params);
```

The function in the module is this one:

```
class SugarFieldAutoincrement extends SugarFieldBase {

    /**
     * Override the SugarFieldBase::save() function to implement the logic to get the next autoincrement value
     * and format the saved value based on the attributes defined for the field.
     *
     * @param SugarBean bean - the bean performing the save
     * @param array params - an array of paramester relevant to the save, most likely will be $_REQUEST
     * @param string field - the name of the field
     */
    public function save(&$bean, $params, $field, $properties, $prefix = '') {
    }
}
```

How can I make sure, that this function is also triggered, when adding leads via SOAP API?

Thanks a lot for your help! :-)

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set the field type to 'autoincrement' and the dbType to 'int' in the vardef record for the field.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the Database has a UUID() trigger on insert for most tables, so you should be able to completely remove the id field.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger the function before saving, you can use beforeSave logic hook.